# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax

Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
at HTMLParagraphElement. ((index):33)
at HTMLParagraphElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
at HTMLParagraphElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
Часть кода:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#load").bind("click", function() {
        var admin = "Admin";
        $.ajax({
            url: "content.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {name: admin},
            dataType: "html",
            beforeSend: funcBefore,
            success: funcSuccess
        });
    });
});
```

Не понимаю почему при подключении других версий jQuery ошибка с той же версией 3.2.1, даже при очистке кэша
Подключал так:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Пробовал так же $.post() и вместо $ jQuery. Ajax я только изучаю и уже ошибки пошли, делал все как в видео..

Comment: библиотека jquery должна подключаться до подключения остальных скриптов

Comment: Самая 1 подключается, остальные функции jQuery работают!

Comment: @Cheg, если бы дело было в очередности, то в консоль бы вывалилось, что $ не определен, а не то что ajax не является функцией

Comment: ты уверен, что подключаешь именно этот скрипт? В тексте ошибки значится slim версия, которая не содержит ajax

Comment: Ну подключал с cdn google пробовал с jquery cdn, пробовал старые версии, указывал обычную, но ошибка 1 и та же, даже скачивал код, и смотрел в нем есть ajax, я вообще не понимаю при чем тут slim

Comment: ну тогда скидывай все исходники (что и где подключаешь, что у тебя в JSе) ...

Comment: index.html https://pastebin.com/TScarkH5
а content.php: https://pastebin.com/F1UTdKcT

Comment: Удали <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Точно) Не заметил что bootstrap тоже jQuery берет только slim. Вот только код не работает, что не так?

Comment: Так бутстрап и работает, вносит кучу фигни в код которую потом переопределять приходится

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Попал на такую же ошибку. Бился в конвульсиях пытаясь понять откуда эта ошибка... нигде ответа нет. потом случайно заметил, что все с этим косяком используют слим версию - jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
надо скачать обычную версию и косяк автоматом пропадает... 5 часов убил на это)))

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек, скопировал скрипты из QuickStart Bootstrap 4, там как раз ссылка на slim, на этом и встал.

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Очень помогло...

Comment: так как подключил то полную версию jquery?