# Не отправляется запрос из textarea в базу данных, с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

При вводе текста в текстовой зоне, в базе данных не сохраняются данные.
В консоли пишет что ajax не является функцией.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.
вот код:

```
$('#diary').bind('input propertychange', function() {

            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "updateData.php",
              data: { content: $("#diary").val() }
            });
```

и еще скрин со страницы:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На скрине же написано «$.ajax is not a function». Какая буква непонятна?

Comment: я это и написал, а что не так с кодом не могу понять

Comment: Либо не та версия jQuery подключена, либо подключена не в том месте, где надо, либо вообще не подключена

Comment: И, кстати, такие вопросы для начала гуглятся: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710508/uncaught-typeerror-ajax-is-not-a-function

Comment: Спасибо, humster_spb !!! нашел ответ